# Character when collides with trigger doesn't change position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working with unity for a couple of days and probably missing something because the character doesn't move to the position of the checkpoint.

code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RespawnScript : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private Transform player;
[SerializeField] private Transform respawnPoint;

void onTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
   player.transform.position = respawnPoint.transform.position;
}
```

}

Comment: The function you are looking for is [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html). Functions are case-sensitive. If you add a `Debug.Log` or a break-point to the code you will see it is never called.

Answer (score 1):

It's `OnTriggerEnter()` not `onTriggerEnter()` , case sensitive. ([Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html))